# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Flink task-managers

Tags: scala, apache-flink

We are running Flink 1.14.4 in Kubernetes, with Kafka source & sink, and async operation of writing bulks to Elasticsearch between them.
We are using `WindowedStream` and wait for 3 seconds to aggregate events, and makes sure that events with the same `itemId` will be handled together. If we get 100 events before that, we want to fire an aync bulk call (with 100 actions) to Elasticsearch.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    val validRawEvents: DataStream[SingleAction] =
      rawStream.
        flatMap(new InputEventsCounter).
        assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(DeltaRcomEsEventTimeExtractor())

    val keyedStream: KeyedStream[(Int, SingleAction), Tuple] = validRawEvents map {
      action: SingleAction => (MurmurHash3.stringHash(action.itemId)%parallelism, action)
    } keyBy 0

    implicit val bulkTypeInfo: TypeInformation[BulkRequest] = TypeInformation.of(classOf[BulkRequest])
    implicit val responseTypeInfo: TypeInformation[(BulkRequest, Iterable[(Int, SingleAction)])] =
      TypeInformation.of(classOf[(BulkRequest, Iterable[(Int, SingleAction)])])
    implicit val transactionLogEntryTypeInfo: TypeInformation[TransactionLogEntry] =
      TypeInformation.of(classOf[TransactionLogEntry])

    val windowStream: WindowedStream[(Int, SingleAction), Tuple, TimeWindow] =
      keyedStream.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(30000)))
    val triggeredWindowStream = windowStream trigger EventTrigger[TimeWindow](windowMaxCount, 30000)
    val processedStream: DataStream[(BulkRequest, Iterable[(Int, SingleAction)])] =
      triggeredWindowStream
        .process(new TriggerProcessWindowFunction()(elasticsearchEndpoints))
        .map(new EsBulkQuerySizeCounter)

    val asyncResOpt: DataStream[Option[(Option[(Iterable[(Int, SingleAction)], Response[BulkResponse])], Long)]] =
      AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(
        processedStream,
        ElasticsearchAsyncFunction(elasticsearchEndpoints),
        esTimeout,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        maxConcurrentAsyncOperations
      )

    val asyncRes = asyncResOpt.flatMap(new ESQueryTimeSummary)

    asyncRes addSink kafkaSink
```

We are getting a lot of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
2023-10-30 10:52:52,269 INFO  com.dy.streamAggregators.deltaRcomElasticsearch.windows.TriggerProcessWindowFunction [] - Bulk requests query batch size: 100
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at com.dy.streamAggregators.deltaRcomElasticsearch.windows.TriggerProcessWindowFunction$$anonfun$process$1.apply(EventTrigger.scala:66)
    at com.dy.streamAggregators.deltaRcomElasticsearch.windows.TriggerProcessWindowFunction$$anonfun$process$1.apply(EventTrigger.scala:50)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:293)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Any idea why we're getting this exception every few minutes? (most of the bulk requests succeed, but some of them fails with the exception above)

**EDIT**: when reducing our task managers to 1 (from 10) - the issue is gone, this exception happens only with more than one task-manager